# Why even have hash tables?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

Hash tables allow mapping keys to values by using a hashing function. Here the hashing function actually computes the index of the key mapped to a specific value. But I just can't get my head around why we even use hash tables it in the first place? Why do you need a hash table? Are maps/dictionaries not good enough? Why not declare a dictionary (`{'key1': 'value1'}` in Python) and use it in the places where a hash table is required? I read a lot about it and still don't get it. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: Very short answer - It is group similar keys and their values. Values could be a list or a count or something else depending on situtation.  If you mention what exactly you don't understand then  we can elaborate on that.

Comment: The map/dictionary are some sort of high level representation, where they use the low level data structures to implement it (like hash table, RB tree, AVL tree, etc).

Comment: You do not need to implement a hashtable unless you actually required it. For example, C++ map, Python dictionary are very good alternative for maintaining key-value in many places. But, you might need to implement your own hashtable, for example, if you need to design a low-level data structure which is optimized w.r.t. some constraint. Map/dictionary is some sort of API where you do not have any control to improve the performance.

Comment: @biqarboy: In C++ `std::map` is not a hashtable. You'd want `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do you need a hashtable, is the map/dictionary not good

This is like asking why you need an automotive engine, isn't a car good enough? An engine is how a car works; you just don't see the engine when you are *driving* the car. But if you are learning to become an automotive engineer, then you should learn how engines work and how to design, build and maintain them.

Likewise, a hash table is how a dictionary works, you just don't see the hash table if you are writing code that *uses* a dictionary. But if you are learning to become a computer scientist, then you should learn how hash tables and other data structures work, and how to design, build and maintain them.

Comment: Specifically a hash table is a very common implementation of a dictionary. A dictionary is an abstract data type that allows storage and lookup of values by keys. Dictionaries can also be implemented efficiently with search trees (like BSTs or B-Trees, different trade-offs to hash maps). I think that the commonness of a Dictionary type in standard libraries that is a hashmap backed dictionary doesn't help to clarify the distinction.

Comment: @moreON The question references Python specifically, in which the built-in `dict` data type is implemented using a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel bad for asking. I have been researching hashes and hash tables for days and there is yet to find person that can explain them simply.
For what I can gather, hash tables are not needed unless you wish to link the hash to another value or values in a table. If you just wish to hash a password and then use the has to compare against future passwords entered using an if statement a table is not required. I also believe that if the hash value is very large it is generally worked into a smaller value (a key) to be used as an index in the table. It is better to have a larger table to reduce the chance the that there are to identical keys that come from the same hash. They call this a collision. In smaller tables where collisions may occur, the record for the table is more of a list with multiple values that can be search through using some other key or variable value.